# Multiple moving objects simultaneously

Tags: matlab

I need to make multiple objects moving at the same time in the MATLAB environment.
I have made a code for three objects moving. However, these object are moving consecutively. I need to see all objects are moving at the same time.

```
% Create data
t = -4:0.1:4;    % Time data
x = t; % Position data
y = x; % Position data

h = plot(x(1),0,'o','MarkerSize',20,'MarkerFaceColor','g');

xlim([-5,5]);
ylim([-5,5]);
grid on

% Animation Loop one
i = 1;

while i<=length(x)
    set(h,'XData',x(i), 'YData',y(i));

          drawnow;
     M(i) = getframe(1);
        i=i+1;

end

hold on

t = -4:0.1:4;    % Time data
x = t; % Position data
y = -x; % Position data
h = plot(x(1),0,'o','MarkerSize',20,'MarkerFaceColor','r');
i = 1;
while i<=length(x)
    set(h,'XData',x(i), 'YData',y(i));

          drawnow;
     M(i) = getframe(1);
        i=i+1;

end


hold on

t = -4:0.1:4;    % Time data
x = t; % Position data

h = plot(x(1),0,'o','MarkerSize',20,'MarkerFaceColor','b');
i = 1;
while i<=length(x)
    set(h,'XData',x(i));

          drawnow;
     M(i) = getframe(1);
        i=i+1;

end
```

Comment: Do you want them to appear as they are moving at the same time or do you want the code that moves the objects to be executed in parallell (i.e. like threading) so that the objects are moving at the same time?

Comment: I  need all objects move at the same time so  a window shows me all objects are moving at with different speeds and direction. Currently, when the one finished its moving then the second one appears..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you'd like to try this:

```
    % Create data
    t = -4:0.1:40;    % Time data
    x = t; % Position data
    y = x; % Position data
    x1 = x;
    y1 = -y;
    h = plot(x(1),y(1),'o','MarkerSize',20,'MarkerFaceColor','g');
    hold on
    h1 = plot(x1(1),y1(1),'o','MarkerSize',20,'MarkerFaceColor','r');
    hold on
    xlim([0,50]);
    ylim([-50,50]);
    grid on
    % Animation Loop one
    i = 1;
    while i<=length(x)
        set(h,'XData',x(i), 'YData',y(i));
        set(h1,'XData',x1(i), 'YData',y1(i));
              drawnow;
         M(i) = getframe(1);
            i=i+1;
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Outer loop must be time (x is your case) and inner loop the objects. That way they will be seen as flying simultaneously. In a somewhat abstract notation:

```
% outer loop over animation time
for time = 1 : last_time
  % inner loop over all objects
  for object = 1 : last_object
    % draw a specific object at a specific time
    draw(object, time);
  end
end
```

Comment: could you apply this to my example please

Comment: @user3481947 But you accepted this answer...? That means that you are satisfied with the answer given.

Comment: Yes I satisfied with the answer. just I want to applied for my example

Comment: Sorry, I do not have enough time for applying the general scheme to your example.